# Unable to pass shell variables into awk

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

I am trying to get data between sequences of numbers, for instance:

```
100000000
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
....
100001000
....
200000000
```

I match the patterns using awk and I can use it successfully without using variables, for instance:

```
awk '/10000000 /{flag=1;next}/10001000/{exit}flag' input.dat
```

However when I try to use shell variables within this command, it gives no output whatsoever:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
    step1=$(($i*10000000))
    step2=$(($step1+1000))
    awk -v arg1="$step1" -v arg2="$step2" '/arg1 /{flag=1;next}/arg2 /{exit}flag' input.dat

done
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex literal `/.../` doesn't allow variables. You can use `~` operator for regex matching in regex with variables:

```
 awk -v arg1="$step1" -v arg2="$step2" '$0 ~ arg1 " "{flag=1; next}
      $0 ~ arg2{exit} flag' input.dat
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that worked very well. However, I'm very new to awk, may I know what does `$0 ~ arg1 " "` do?

Comment: That is regex comparison with variable `arg1` with a space in the end since you had `/10000000 /` in question.